# save null values as multiple keys where null has a single meaning

Tags: java, hashtable, guava

I need a multiple key map and I want to use null values as keys. I am using HashBasedTable which does not allow null keys.

```java
Table<String, String, JsonObject> table = HashBasedTable.create();
String key1= null, key2= null;
table.put(key1, key2, value);
```

How can I achieve the same. Please help. Thanks

Comment: you can use also a Map<Key,Map<Key,Value>> so you will have the first map with a key, and the value is a map with the second key, in this case you can have only one null key per map. i don't know if you need multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), in that case a string which you know is not part of the possible set of strings (e.g. `"Unknown"`):

```
Table<String, String, JsonObject> table = HashBasedTable.create();
String key1 = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(realKey1, "Unknown"),
        key2 = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(realKey2, "Unknown");
table.put(key1, key2, value);
```

You can also use `Optional<String>` to wrap your keys instead, and then your null object becomes `Optional.empty()` (or `Optional.absent()` if you use Guava's `Optional`):

```
Table<Optional<String>, Optional<String>, JsonObject> table = HashBasedTable.create();
Optional<String> key1 = Optional.ofNullable(realKey1),
        key2 = Optional.ofNullable(realKey2);
table.put(key1, key2, value);
```